# Create a form with nested associations

Tags: cakephp

Suppose I have a models A, B, and C with:

```
class A extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'B1' => array(
            'className' => 'B',
            ...
        ),
        'B2' => array(
            'className' => 'B',
            ...
        )
    );

    ...
}

class B extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'A';

    public $hasOne = array(
        'C' => array(
            'className' => 'C',
            ...
        )
    );

    ...
}

class C extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'B';
}
```

I would like to allow the user to edit fields of an instance/row of A and the associated instances/rows of A.B1, A.B2, A.B1.C, and A.B2.C. I know I can do

```
echo $this->Form->create('A');
echo $this->Form->input('A.some_field');

echo $this->Form->input('B1.some_field');
echo $this->Form->input('B2.some_field');
...

echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
```

and use saveAll to save the request, but how do I reference fields in A.B1.C and A.B2.C? I tried B1.C.some_field and B2.C.some_field but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Depends what version of Cake you're using

As of 2.1 [saveAll saves unlimited levels deep](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#new-features-in-cakephp-2-1), as such the answer is the same/similar to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734536/create-a-form-with-associations):

```
echo $this->Form->create('A');
echo $this->Form->input('A.id');

echo $this->Form->input('B.0.some_field');
echo $this->Form->input('B.0.C.name');
echo $this->Form->input('B.1.some_field');
echo $this->Form->input('B.0.C.name');
...

echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
```

That will generate data in the same format that saveAll expects, if using the [deep option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array):

```
function edit($id) {
    ...
    $success = $this->A->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
}
```